# API for transferring iTunes gift card to user?

Tags: api, itunes, itunes-store

Is there a way to programmatically transfer an iTunes gift card to some user?

Or credit an iTunes account?

Thanks!

Comment: Nope, not yet ... any clues yourself?

Comment: Any update on this now that it is almost 2 years later?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a chat with the Apple customer care and they told me that it is not possible to do this programmatically (right now). They said that we can either download iTunes and use the interface to send a virtual iTunes gift card or buy and send a physical gift card.

Since I wanted to have an API(ish) support for this she said the only way was to talk to someone from business relations at Apple.

Hope this information helps.

Answer (score 0):

Tango Card can deliver iTunes eCards via API (pending approval), along with many other retailers. API is open source and no fees to integrate or ever. Check out the Github site here: https://github.com/tangocarddev

Comment: We've built a ruby gem for interfacing with the Tangocard RaaS API: https://github.com/bonusly/tangocard

Comment: The repo is empty